# How to fix the pagination showing page/1/

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am using `paginate_links()` and pagination work fine but My problem here is that when you go back to page 1 it shows `(www.mysite.com/collections/page/1/)` when it should send back to its parent or main page `www.mysite.com/collections/`

`www.mysite.com/collections`
and
`www.mysite.com/collections/page/1/`
are the same page but the URL structure is different, how can I fix so that page 1 should go to its main page and don't have the page/1 thing.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
    $first = ( $per_page * $paged ) - $per_page;
    $last  = min( $total, $per_page * $paged );
    $current = isset( $paged ) ? $paged : wc_get_loop_prop( 'current_page' );
    $base    = isset( $base ) ? '' : esc_url_raw( str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', remove_query_arg( 'add-to-cart', get_pagenum_link( 999999999, false ) ) ) );
    $format  = isset( $format ) ? '?page=%#%' : '%#%';

            echo paginate_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pagination_args', array( // WPCS: XSS ok.
                'base'         => $base,
                'format'       => $format,
                'add_args'     => false,
                'current'      => max( 1, $current ),
                'total'        => ceil($total / $per_page),
                'prev_text'    => '&larr;',
                'next_text'    => '&rarr;',
                'type'         => 'list',
                'end_size'     => 3,
                'mid_size'     => 3,
            ) ) );

        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change it using jquery

```
if($('.pagination a:first').attr('href') === "http://yoursite.com/page/1")
{
   $(".pagination a:first").attr("href", "http://yoursite.com/");
}
$(".pagination a:nth-child(2)").attr("href", "http://yoursite.com/");
```

Comment: The problem here is the this url www.mysite.com/collections/page/1/ can be like this also www.mysite.com/collections/marbles/page/1/

Comment: collection is a custom post type while there will be taxonomies associated